# Problem extracting the right information with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to extract specific information from a website with BeautifulSoup, but not yet found the right way to to it. The website hast the following information:

B. Hübner wechselt für 3.711.638 von Computer zu Marcel.

Ginczek wechselt für 2.845.000 von Computer zu Max.

Embolo wechselt für 6.640.000 von Computer zu Chrissi.

Jäkel wechselt für 220.000 von Thilo zu Computer.

Raphaël Guerreiro wechselt für 3.640.000 von Malte zu Computer.

Which looks like the following in the source code:

```
<div class="article_content2">
 <div class="article_content_text">
  <a href="../../bundesligaspieler/32426-B.+H%C3%BCbner.html" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/32426-B.+H%C3%BCbner.html','44f6'))" style="font-weight:normal;" target="_blank">
   B. Hübner
  </a>
  wechselt für 3.711.638 von Computer zu
  <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059320" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059320','p_13059320'))" style="font-weight:normal;" target="_blank">
   Marcel
  </a>
  .
  <br/>
  <a href="../../bundesligaspieler/31700-Ginczek.html" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/31700-Ginczek.html','44f6'))" style="font-weight:normal;" target="_blank">
   Ginczek
  </a>
  wechselt für 2.845.000 von Computer zu
  <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059734" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059734','p_13059734'))" style="font-weight:normal;" target="_blank">
   Max
  </a>
  .
  <br/>
  <a href="../../bundesligaspieler/32642-Embolo.html" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/32642-Embolo.html','44f6'))" style="font-weight:normal;" target="_blank">
   Embolo
  </a>
  wechselt für 6.640.000 von Computer zu
  <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059329" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059329','p_13059329'))" style="font-weight:normal;" target="_blank">
   Chrissi
  </a>
  .
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a href="../../bundesligaspieler/33109-J%C3%A4kel.html" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/33109-J%C3%A4kel.html','44f6'))" style="font-weight:normal;" target="_blank">
   Jäkel
  </a>
  wechselt für 220.000 von
  <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059353" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059353','p_13059353'))" style="font-weight:normal;" target="_blank">
   Thilo
  </a>
  zu Computer.
  <br/>
  <a href="../../bundesligaspieler/32632-Rapha%C3%ABl+Guerreiro.html" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/32632-Rapha%C3%ABl+Guerreiro.html','44f6'))" style="font-weight:normal;" target="_blank">
   Raphaël Guerreiro
  </a>
  wechselt für 3.640.000 von
  <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059325" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059325','p_13059325'))" style="font-weight:normal;" target="_blank">
   Malte
  </a>
  zu Computer.
  <br/>
  <br/>
 </div>
</div>
```

So far I have only managed to pull the whole code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("https://classic.comunio.de/login.phtml?login=USER&pass=PASSWORD")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

player_all = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('bundesligaspieler'))
```

As an output I would like to get something like this:

Füllkrug, 4.787.771,  Computer,  Marcel

Sergio Córdova, 379.000, Computer, Thilo

J. Boateng, 2.164.007, Computer, Marcel

Stindl, 5.922.500, Niklas, Computer

Comment: Is the HTML you're getting `r.text` as you expect? Because logging in with a GET request doesn't seem right `requests.get`.

Comment: Yes, it looks fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the HTML you're getting `r.text` as you expect? Because logging in with a GET request `requests.get` doesn't seem right. You need to make a POST request like below.

Then to extract exchange details, I've walked over all strings and tried to match every two people to whatever exchange happened between them.

```
import csv
import re
from io import StringIO
from pprint import pprint
from typing import IO

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_report_html():
    res = requests.post('https://classic.comunio.de/login.phtml', data={
        "login": "your_username",
        "pass": "your_password",
        "action": "login",
        ">>+Login": "-1"
    })
    res.raise_for_status()
    return res.text


def parse_exchange_details(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> list:
    name_els = soup.select('.article_content_text a')
    person_names = [a.text.strip() for a in name_els]

    exchanges = []

    persons = []
    action = None
    amount = None
    for s in soup.stripped_strings:
        if s in person_names:
            persons.append(s)

        # determine exchange direction
        if 'von Computer zu' in s:
            action = 'withdraw'
        elif 'zu Computer' in s:
            action = 'deposit'

        # look for numbers
        m = re.search('(\d[\d.]+)', s)
        if m:
            amount = m.group(1)

        # did we collect all exchange details
        if len(persons) == 2 and action and amount:
            p1, p2 = persons
            if action == 'deposit':
                from_, to = p2, 'computer'
            else:
                from_, to = 'computer', p2

            exc = {
                'who': p1,
                'amount': amount,
                'from': from_,
                'to': to
            }
            exchanges.append(exc)

            # reset for the next exchange
            persons = []
            action = None
            amount = None
    return exchanges

def write_csv(file: IO, report: list):
    fields = list(report[0].keys())
    w = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
    for item in report:
        w.writerow(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    html = '''
<div class="article_content2">
 <div class="article_content_text">
  <a>B. Hübner</a> wechselt für 3.711.638 von Computer zu <a>Marcel</a> .
  <br/>
  <a>Ginczek</a> wechselt für 2.845.000 von Computer zu <a>Max</a> .
  <br/>
  <a>Embolo</a> wechselt für 6.640.000 von Computer zu <a>Chrissi</a> .
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a>Jäkel</a> wechselt für 220.000 von <a>Thilo</a> zu Computer.
  <br/>
  <a>Raphaël Guerreiro</a> wechselt für 3.640.000 von <a>Malte</a> zu Computer.
  <br/>
  <br/>
 </div>
</div>
    '''
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    exchanges = parse_exchange_details(soup)
    pprint(exchanges, width=200)

    file = StringIO()
    # or `with open('filename.csv', 'w') as file:` 
    write_csv(file, exchanges)
    file.seek(0)
    print(file.read())
```

output:

```
[{'amount': '3.711.638', 'from': 'computer', 'to': 'Marcel', 'who': 'B. Hübner'},
 {'amount': '2.845.000', 'from': 'computer', 'to': 'Max', 'who': 'Ginczek'},
 {'amount': '6.640.000', 'from': 'computer', 'to': 'Chrissi', 'who': 'Embolo'},
 {'amount': '220.000', 'from': 'Thilo', 'to': 'computer', 'who': 'Jäkel'},
 {'amount': '3.640.000', 'from': 'Malte', 'to': 'computer', 'who': 'Raphaël Guerreiro'}]

B. Hübner,3.711.638,computer,Marcel
Ginczek,2.845.000,computer,Max
Embolo,6.640.000,computer,Chrissi
Jäkel,220.000,Thilo,computer
Raphaël Guerreiro,3.640.000,Malte,computer
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that will help me to navigate also to other pages and not just the home directory. But the output (r.text) for the page I'm looking at right now is the same

Comment: I'm really greatful for the code you posted here, I'm still trying to figure it out since 2h :D

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with the system, here, but yes ofc I will do that. I posted another answer with the difficulties I run into

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html3, 'html.parser')
name_els = soup.select('.article_content_text a')
person_names = [a.text.strip() for a in name_els]
exchanges = []

persons = []
action = None
amount = None
for s in soup.stripped_strings:
        if s in person_names:
            persons.append(s)
 # determine exchange direction
        if 'von Computer zu' in s:
            action = 'withdraw'
        elif 'zu Computer' in s:
            action = 'deposit'
        elif 'von ' in s:
            action = 'swap'
        # look for numbers
        m = re.search('(\d[\d.]+)', s)
        if m:
            amount = m.group(1)        

        # did we collect all exchange details
        if len(persons) == 2  and action:
            p1, p2 = persons
            if action == 'deposit':
                from_, to = p2, 'computer'
            else:
                from_, to = 'computer', p2       

        if len(persons) == 3 and action:
            p1, p2, p3 = persons
            if action == 'swap':
                 from_, to = p2, p3

            exc = {
                'who': p1,
                'amount': amount,
                'from': from_,
                'to': to
            }
            exchanges.append(exc)

            # reset for the next exchange
            persons = []
            action = None
            amount = None

pprint(exchanges, width=200)
```

Islightly tried to modify the code, since there is also the swap between two players possible, which I forgot about initially. Here is an example of the html code of one of those sections.

```
<div class="article_content_text">
            <a href="../../bundesligaspieler/32780-Tolisso.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/32780-Tolisso.html','7cbb'))">Tolisso</a> wechselt für 8.640.000 von Computer zu <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059329" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059329','p_13059329'))">Chrissi</a>.<br><a href="../../bundesligaspieler/32897-L%C3%B6wen.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/32897-L%C3%B6wen.html','7cbb'))">Löwen</a> wechselt für 2.712.122 von Computer zu <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059337" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059337','p_13059337'))">Niklas</a>.<br><a href="../../bundesligaspieler/31740-Plattenhardt.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/31740-Plattenhardt.html','7cbb'))">Plattenhardt</a> wechselt für 2.260.000 von Computer zu <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059734" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059734','p_13059734'))">Max</a>.<br><a href="../../bundesligaspieler/32845-Sancho.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/32845-Sancho.html','7cbb'))">Sancho</a> wechselt für 14.118.000 von Computer zu <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059315" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059315','p_13059315'))">Dennis</a>.<br><br><a href="../../bundesligaspieler/32584-Demme.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/32584-Demme.html','7cbb'))">Demme</a> wechselt für 2.603.700 von <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060984" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060984','p_13060984'))">Johannes</a> zu Computer.<br><a href="../../bundesligaspieler/33108-Stierlin.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/33108-Stierlin.html','7cbb'))">Stierlin</a> wechselt für 163.200 von <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060984" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060984','p_13060984'))">Johannes</a> zu Computer.<br><a href="../../bundesligaspieler/32374-Kosti%C4%87.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/32374-Kosti%C4%87.html','7cbb'))">Kostić</a> wechselt für 7.068.600 von <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059315" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059315','p_13059315'))">Dennis</a> zu Computer.<br><a href="../../bundesligaspieler/31372-Hitz.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/31372-Hitz.html','7cbb'))">Hitz</a> wechselt für 222.200 von <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060984" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060984','p_13060984'))">Johannes</a> zu Computer.<br><br><a href="../../bundesligaspieler/33026-Kabak.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/33026-Kabak.html','7cbb'))">Kabak</a> wechselt für 300.000 von <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059320" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059320','p_13059320'))">Marcel</a> zu <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060183" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060183','p_13060183'))">Olé Sané</a>.<br><a href="../../bundesligaspieler/33096-Trimmel.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/33096-Trimmel.html','7cbb'))">Trimmel</a> wechselt für 0 von <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060183" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060183','p_13060183'))">Olé Sané</a> zu <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059320" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059320','p_13059320'))">Marcel</a>.<br><a href="../../bundesligaspieler/32208-Dahoud.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('../../bundesligaspieler/32208-Dahoud.html','7cbb'))">Dahoud</a> wechselt für 0 von <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060183" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13060183','p_13060183'))">Olé Sané</a> zu <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059320" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;" onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=13059320','p_13059320'))">Marcel</a>.
            </div>
```